# Run multiple queries with Common Table Expression

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression

Currently I have a query using `WITH` clause that I'm using to get a list of IDs from two separate tables that I plan on `DELETE`ing.

```
WITH ids_to_delete AS (SELECT org.uuid, person.uuid FROM organizations org INNER JOIN people person ON org.uuid = person.org_uuid)
```

The issue is that I need to use this same statement in two separate `DELETE` queries.  One for the `organizations` table and one for the `people` table.  However, if I semicolon separate these statements I lose access to `ids_to_delete`, and if I simply run the query again I will not get the same results.

I would like to be able to do something like this to keep access to my `ids_to_delete` results:

```
WITH ids_to_delete AS (SELECT org.uuid, person.uuid FROM organizations 
org INNER JOIN people person ON org.uuid = person.org_uuid),
DELETE FROM organizations WHERE uuid IN (SELECT org.uuid FROM ids_to_delete), 
DELETE FROM people WHERE uuid IN (SELECT person.uuid FROM ids_to_delete);
```

Additionally Organizations->People is a Many-to-one relationship, enforced by a `FOREIGN KEY`, so I need to delete the people first.

Using PostgreSQL 9.6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Postgres supports `delete` in CTEs.  So you can phrase this as one query:

```
WITH ids_to_delete AS (
      SELECT org.uuid, person.uuid
      FROM organizations org INNER JOIN
           people person
           ON org.uuid = person.org_uuid
     ),
     o as (
      DELETE FROM organizations
      WHERE uuid IN (SELECT org.uuid FROM ids_to_delete)
      RETURNING org.uuid
     ) 
DELETE FROM people
WHERE uuid IN (SELECT person.uuid FROM ids_to_delete);
```